# Backbone render Data from Mongodb without Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

I want to render Data from mongodb in a view, but I don't want to create an collection or model..

My idea was it to add something like this into the render function of my default view:

```
var myVar = 'sup fresh our turn baby!';
var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myArea');
myTextArea.innerHTML += myVar;
```

This does work.

My problem is how to get the data(wich is already in a variable) from my server.js (nodejs) into the backbone view.

Which is the best way to get the data?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using Backbone if you don't need Models and Collections and appending data like described above?

Comment: I use Models and Collections. But I only want to render this special Type of Data...there is no need to create an Model.

Comment: That special data should be somehow fetched from your server. After that you should append it to you html/template. If you don't want to use Backbone, just fetch it via `$.ajax`.